# How would I monitor if a new entity had been saved?

Tags: entities

I am creating a module that I want to run when an entity is saved. I have used rules in the past but the overhead on the module means that I cannot use it. Is there another way that I can do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it to run for all entities, then your module can implement [`hook_entity_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7) for new entities and [`hook_entity_update()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/7) for changes to existing ones.

If you just need to target specific ones (node, user, etc), then most of the modules that implement entities also have `insert` and `update` hooks.

Comment: Dang beaten to the punch ;-p +1 for the better descriptions

Comment: Is there a possibility to give a small example of how it would be implemented?

Comment: @Andrew the docs pages have got examples that should help

Comment: I think I got my head around it after digging around in the docs. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[`hook_entity_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7) sounds like what you're after.

> Act on entities when inserted.